# how to de-duplicate the record in data frame without null value in rows in python using record linkage toolkit?

Tags: nlp, duplicates, string-matching, python-re, record-linkage

This is the data frame, here i need to deduplicate the records, for dedup the record there i need to exclude the not available value and compare with other each records.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'fname':['richard','patricia','william','michael','richard','william'],
'lname': ['dietzen','economides','macdonald','boothby','dietzen','macdonald'],
'contact':['18708667706','not available','12404471426','18177395663','18708667706','12404471426'],
'bus_contact':['not available','12406789540','15619984476','not available','not available','15619984476'],
'email':['not available','patricia.economides@gmail.com','dpjpropertymanagement@gmail.com','mboothby@osmifw.com','not available','dpjpropertymanagement@gmail.com'],
'bus_mail':['rdietzen@hotmail.com','wmacdonald@mcrtrust.com','not available','michael.boothby@yahoo.com','rdietzen@hotmail.com','abc.com']})
```

this is my code for record linkage

```
 import recordlinkage
 indexer = recordlinkage.Index()
 indexer.block("LASTNAME")
 candidate_links = indexer.index(master_data)

 compare = recordlinkage.Compare()

 compare.string("fname", "fname", method="jarowinkler", threshold=0.85, missing_value = 'not available', label="fname")

compare.string("lname", "lname", method="jarowinkler", threshold=0.85, missing_value = 'not available', label="lname")
compare.exact("contact", "contact", missing_value = 'not available', label='contact')
compare.exact("bus_contact", "bus_contact", missing_value = 'not available', label="bus_contact")
compare.string("email", "email", method="jarowinkler", threshold=0.85,

          missing_value='not available', label="email")
compare.string("bus_mail", "bus_mail", method="jarowinkler", threshold=0.85,
           missing_value='not available', label="bus_mail")
features = compare.compute(candidate_links, df)
```

actual output of record linkage score:

```
|      | fname| lname| contact| bus_contact| email | bus_mail|
|      |-----------------------------------------------------|
|(4, 0)|  1   |  1  |  1      |   1        |  1    |   1     |
|(5, 2)|  1   |  1  |  1      |   1        |  1    |   0     |
```

expected output of record linkage score should be exclude the not available value when compute the scores. assume it as NaN value

expected output of record linkage score:

```
|      | fname| lname| contact| bus_contact| email | bus_mail|
|      |-----------------------------------------------------|
|(4, 0)|  1   |  1  |  1      |   0        |  0    |   1     |
|(5, 2)|  1   |  1  |  1      |   1        |  1    |   0     |
```

If the both records are not available it should be return as 0. please can anyone help me out.